# Who writes the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

Where do the contents of the FAQ come from? Are they written by the Meta community? By MSE moderators? Elsewhere?

How much does it reflect the attitudes that have developed here over time? And does it have a means to evolve as attitudes change?

Comment: Who writes the FAQ? If this question were asked more often it would appear in the FAQ. I smell a Berry paradox variant!

Comment: Do you mean [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) on the main site or the questions tagged [faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) at meta?

Comment: @Martin: The faq on the main site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The section "What kind of question can I ask here" is editable by the moderators of this site. The other parts are constant for all SE sites.

The moderators typically don't decide alone what they put into the FAQ, but changes are discussed on meta before. If you think something specific should be changed in the FAQ, just open a meta topic and propose some changes.

Comment: Wait.   Is that the new word to refer to the entire board of moderators: the *moderatory* ??

Comment: No, the y is just pretty close to the s on my keyboard.

Comment: Speaking not at all on behalf of the rest of the moderatory, I say we keep the word.\

Comment: For example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436/a-theorem-on-mains-faq  led to some grammar changes.